# trouble with linq query for inner join and left join

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 3 tables named `Posts`, `Tags` and `PostXTags` that `PostXTags` is connector between Posts and Tags.

I tried to make the following query in linq But I've never achieved a ideal result.

Please help me write the correct linq this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts
INNER JOIN PostXTags
ON Posts.PostID = PostXTags.PostID
LEFT JOIN Tags
ON PostXTags.TagID = Tags.TagID
```

Comment: post the Linq query you have tried.

Comment: The sole effect of the `LEFT JOIN` in that SQL would be to cause some of the rows from `POSTS` to be repeated. I'm guessing that's not what you actually want.  It would help if you showed the actual problem you are trying to solve instead of a made-up example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from p in Posts
            join x in PostXTags on p.PostID equals x.PostID
            join t in Tags on x.TagID equals t.TagID into joinedTags
            from t in joinedTags.DefaultIfEmpty()  //left join                
            select new { Posts = p, Tags = t };    //t could be null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve this:

```
var query = context.Tags.Where(t => t.Id == id).SelectMany(t => t.Posts);
```